# How to ressign ctags for a different key binding in Vim?

Tags: vim, ctags, cscope

I'm using Vim, the default binding for Cscope is the same one with Ctags (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>), but I want to assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> for Ctags and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> for Cscope so that I can use one find definitions and the other for references. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `<C-]>` is not the default binding for cscope and ctags. It is used for both only if you explicitely tell Vim to do so with `set cscopetag`.

`:h cscope-suggestions` as a few good suggestions for you.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> use the same escape sequences on the terminal therefore vim will not be able to distinguish between the two.

For more info see:

```
:h escape
```